# 90s/80s Cartoon with rebel helper robots resembling transformers?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, episode-identification

I can distinctly remember watching some 15 years ago a cartoon where in robots were helpers to humans in a futuristic city. A faction of Robots (and perhaps humans, even maybe predominataely humans) however were some how rebelling against the status quo.

I specifically remember one scene where a bunch of kids are playing baseball, and drawing up teams. A helper robot is then asked to join one team. The other team complains but they eventually allow it.

Does this ring any bells? The robots all seemed very much like Transformers, but I'm fairly certain they weren't.

**Edit:** It's not unlikely that I'm wrong and this is an episode from one of the older Transformers shows... I've re-tagged appropriately.

Comment: The only cartoon from the 80s that I recall resembling Transformers is: [Gobots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobots).

Comment: I'm not sure...perhpas this was a transformers episode?

Comment: Perhaps it's the [Headmasters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headmaster_(Transformers)) or even [Targetmasters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targetmaster), both which came from Transformers?

Comment: I don't recall that kind of an episode for either Transformers or GoBots, but it's been quite a while since I've seen any GoBots.

Comment: What language was it and where was it? Can you describe the robots?

Comment: @Wikis english, and they looked like the transformers from the 80s movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Series was called [The Bots Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bots_Master). Here is the [intro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLKYOSiW7U4), as found by DampeS8N.

> In year 2025 A.D., robotics have become commonplace, performing menial tasks and working in industry. For that, the world can thank the young genius robotic engineer Ziv "ZZ" Zulander and the Robotic Megafact Corporation (aka RM Corp) he works for. Ziv's creation of the "3A robot series" revolutionized the world and its application of robotics. However, Sir Lewis Leon Paradim (aka "LLP", president of RM Corp) isn't satisfied being one of the wealthiest men in the world; he desires world domination.
>   With his assistants Lady Frenzy and Dr. Hiss, LLP plans to take control of the planet through a coup, using the very same 3A bots that ZZ had invented to benefit humanity. Dr. Hiss creates a new chip, called the "Krang Chip", which can be used to override any 3A series robot to take orders exclusively from RM Corp. ZZ learns of LLP's evil plan and decides to defect from the company, intending to stop the continued manufacture and distribution of the Krang Chips.
>   ~[Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bots_Master#Summary)

Answer (score 1):

Any of these ring a bell? (warning, this may be nostalgia overload) This is in the order I would guess *might* be the show in question. There are literally a hundred robot 80's shows.

- [Phantom 2040](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De3YLU3GBKI)
- [Mighty Orbots](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0qiFRD0NLzY)
- [Saber Rider](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awxKPdqLHGE)
- [Bionic 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_RdPawsqgo)
- [Robotix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0243726/)
- [Tranzor-Z](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVkueSuO-GU)
- [Silverhawks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mzAQu23t19A)

I'm sorry... I'm so sorry...

Anyway, the plot sounds something like [Appleseed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appleseed_%28OVA%29) but that's a major stretch. Or even [Galaxy Express 999](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080772/) which is way too early but has similar human/non-human themes.

Comment: I thkn I may have found it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bots_Master

Comment: [Wow, that's even worse than the other ones...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLKYOSiW7U4)

Comment: I'll have to check it out when I'm back from work.